# Why (System.in) is passed as parameter while instantiating a new Object of Scanner Class?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Without System.in in the instantiation of scanner class, i am unable to assign any value from my keyboard. What exactly is happening. Can anyone elaborate please.

Comment: Because the scanner class can also read from other sources (like files), you have to tell from where exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to specify where to read from.

Following statements are perfectly valid and read from various sources

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myNumbers"));
```

---

```
String input = "1 fish 2 fish red fish blue fish";
Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
```

---

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

---

So, now you must be clear that `System.in` **need not** be the parameter always while instantiating a Scanner object.

Going ahead, explaining why you are passing `System.in`

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.InputStream))

> public Scanner(InputStream source)
>
> Constructs a new Scanner that produces values **scanned from the
>   specified input stream**. Bytes from the stream are converted into
>   characters using the underlying platform's default charset.

From `java.lang.System`

```
 /**
 * The "standard" input stream. This stream is already
 * open and ready to supply input data. Typically this stream
 * corresponds to keyboard input or another input source specified by
 * the host environment or user.
 */
public final static InputStream in = null;
```

Hope this is self-explanatory!

Answer (score 3):

The value of [`System.in`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#in), which is an instance of `InputStream`, is the ["standard input"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams). As the documentation says:

> The "standard" input stream. This stream is already open and ready to supply input data. Typically this stream corresponds to keyboard input or another input source specified by the host environment or user.

When you use `new Scanner(System.in)` you are using the [`Scanner#<init>(InputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.InputStream)) constructor, whose documentation says:

> Constructs a new `Scanner` that produces values scanned from the specified input stream. Bytes from the stream are converted into characters using the underlying platform's default charset.

As you can see, passing `System.in` simply configures the `Scanner` to read from the standard input. You could of course use a different `InputStream` that reads from somewhere else (e.g. network, file, etc.). If you look at the other constructors of `Scanner` you'll see you can configure many different kinds of sources (e.g. file, `String`, etc.).

Comment: @CharanKumar If this answer helped you should accept it by selecting the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

From Javadoc: Class [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#constructor.summary)

```
| Constructor                                             | Description                                                                            |
|---------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Scanner​(File source)                                    | Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified file.         |
| Scanner​(File source, String charsetName)                | Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified file.         |
| Scanner​(File source, Charset charset)                   | Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified file.         |
| Scanner​(InputStream source)                             | Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified input stream. |
| Scanner​(InputStream source, String charsetName)         | Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified input stream. |
| Scanner​(InputStream source, Charset charset)            | Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified input stream. |
| Scanner​(Readable source)                                | Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified source.       |
| Scanner​(String source)                                  | Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified string.       |
| Scanner​(ReadableByteChannel source)                     | Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified channel.      |
| Scanner​(ReadableByteChannel source, String charsetName) | Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified channel.      |
| Scanner​(Path source)                                    | Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified file.         |
| Scanner​(Path source, String charsetName)                | Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified file.         |
| Scanner​(Path source, Charset charset)                   | Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified file.         |
```

To specify what kind of Scanner you want you have to pass a parameter. System.in tells Scanner class that from `InputStream source`